# How to use Johnny-five in Angular2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2, johnny-five

Please, I am new to `angular2` and I need help implementing Johnny-Five in `angular2`.

I created a provider (J5Provider):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

var raspi = require('raspi-io');
var j5 = require('johnny-five');

@Injectable()
export class J5Provider {
    private board: any;

    constructor() {
        this.board = new j5.Board({
            io: new raspi()
        });

        this.board.on('ready', function () {
            var led = new j5.Led('P1-7');
            led.strobe(500);
        });
    }
}
```

Then I tried to instantiate in `app.module.ts` in an `Ionic2` project:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {J5Provider} from '../providers/j5-provider'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        TabsPage
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        J5Provider,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when I run, I get the following error:

```
repl.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "repl"
    at v (polyfills.js:3)
    at webpackMissingModule (repl.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (repl.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (repl.js:106)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c6de802…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (board.js:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (board.js:1269)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c6de802…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (accelerometer.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (accelerometer.js:1175)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c6de802…:19)
    at Object.noop (johnny-five.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c6de802…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c6de802…:19)
```

Please can anyone guide me on how I can do this implementation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the url of Johnny-Five ?

Comment: where's the code of usage of this `provider`? code of page component?

Comment: Hi, Samph... I installed by npm install johnny-five raspi-io and I tried isntantiate it in step 2: providers: []

Comment: `johnny-five` will run on nodejs. What is your target platform?

Comment: Diullei, nodejs/angular2/typescript or Ionic2

Comment: Did you do this? `IMPORTANT: Once you are done installing Raspi IO for the first time, make sure you reboot before you run any code! This isn't necessary for subsequent installs of Raspi IO` https://github.com/nebrius/raspi-io/wiki/Getting-a-Raspberry-Pi-ready-for-NodeBots

Comment: Yes, I did @Sampath

Comment: No difference? You can get help from here too: https://github.com/nebrius/raspi-io/issues/new